# Need help in Query String

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linq

I have to traverse through the entire schema and get all the table that has a particular column. And then from the table and column I need to search for a particular value and then update that value.

So below is what I have

```
  Public Function MassDataFieldUpdate(ByVal Column As List(Of String), ByVal whereClause As String) As DataTable
        Dim temp As String = ""
        Dim cSQL As String = String.Format("SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE find_in_set(COLUMN_NAME, 'idUnit') > 0")
        Return _Inst.GetTable(cSQL)
    End Function
```

This function returns me a Datatable which is :

[image]

Now I want to write another query/LINQ on datatable and traverse to all the column which has a row value of 24 and change it to 88.

so if in table `tblContact` the column 'idUnit' has value 24 I need to update it to '88' Please guide me.

This is what I have till now:

**LOGIC.VB**

```
 Public Sub MassDataFieldUpdate()
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim Column As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            Select Case mode
                Case SMS_Obj.Enumerations.DataUpdateMode.UnitId
                    Column.Add("idUnit")
                Case SMS_Obj.Enumerations.DataUpdateMode.Unknown
                    ' -1
                Case Else
                    ' nothing
            End Select
            dt.Merge(MassDataFieldUpdate(Column))
            'WHAT LINQ QUERY NEEDS TO BE WRITTEN HERE
            ' I need to call 'MassRowUpdate' HERE
        End Sub
```

**DAL.vb**

```
Public Function MassDataFieldUpdate(ByVal Column As List(Of String)) As DataTable
        Dim temp As String = ""
        Dim cSQL As String = String.Format("SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE find_in_set(COLUMN_NAME, '{0}') > 0)", Column)
        Return _Inst.GetTable(cSQL)
    End Function

    Public Sub MassRowUpdate(ByVal table_name As String, ByVal Column As List(Of String), ByVal whereClause As String)
        Dim cSQL As String = String.Format("UPDATE {0} FROM {1} SET {2} {3}", table_name, Column, whereClause)
    End Sub
```

Comment: That's not a "query string". That's a SQL query. Also, the code is broken; there's no close quote in the purposeless call to `String.Format`. What is the problem you are having writing the other query? What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the Typo. I have updated it. But I need to know do I need to write LINQ query?

Comment: Google UPDATE mysql. First hit.

Comment: I have added more code as per your suggestion. But I think I am still missing the LINQ. Can you guide once.

Comment: If I have done something silly. please point that out. I am a beginner.

Comment: You are trying to put the entire value of `Column` into a string, but `Column` is a `List(Of String)`. To work with your current approach, you will at least need to *iterate* through each item in this List rather than try to operate on the whole list at once.